# Outlook web Addin: how to suppress the default notification message comes up when clicking on the button

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are trying to display a customized message when the users click on our Outlook web-addin button and make the following call,

```
  Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync( 
        'progress', {type: 'progressIndicator', message: msg});
```

However, there is always a default message "[MyAddinName] is working on your [MyButtonLabel] request" showing up before our message comes. Is there a way to suppress that default message?

I have been reading through documents on [Office dev center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) but could not find anything related. Need some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: If it literally says "[MyAddInName]" and "[MyButtonLabel]" it sounds like you probably need to replace those strings in your manifest.xml

Comment: Yes, we figured that out. But we do not want the "...  is working on your ..." part. Want to remove it. Not sure how to do that. Seems that Outlook is generating this message via a template internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial progress notification shows up for UI-less Add-in Commands when the add-in is loading. There is no way for the add-in developer to suppress this notification, however adding a notification will automatically remove the default loading notification when the Add-in is loaded.